# Android: Command not found after installing Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I followed the instructions from [TechApple](http://techapple.net/2014/07/runinstall-official-android-sdk-emulator-linux-ubuntulinuxmint/) on how to install an android emulator. I followed all the steps, restarted the pc, but now I still cannot have my `android avd` command recognized.

The very top of my `~/.bashrc` file is :

```
export PATH=${PATH}:~/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools
```

The error I get is :

```
alex@alex:~/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools$ android avd
android: command not found
```

What do I have to do next in order to get my emulator working?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to run emulator from terminal you need to -

```
cd /usr/local/android-sdk-linux/tools/
./emulator -list-avds
```

This will show all emulators. To choose your emulator -

```
./emulator -avd <avd_name_shown>
```

Answer (score 4):

On Linux, if you want to run a program that's located in the same folder you're in, you have to use **./** in front of the file name.

Just type `./android avd` followed by the rest of the parameters if any.

Comment: Still does not work. I've tried it and I get the same error.